# Rescale image with slider in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I wrote a seam carving implementation in python and would like to be able to interactively rescale an image side by side with the original. I have a slider that adjusts the actual size of the image, however pyplot just stretches it back to the original size!

[image]

How can I prevent this from happening?

```
PATH = "memory.jpeg"
PREPROCESS_SCALE = 0.25
MIN_SCALE = 0.98

ax_scale = plt.axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03], facecolor="black")
scale_slider = Slider(ax = ax_scale,
                      label="Scale",
                      valmin = MIN_SCALE,
                      valmax = 1,
                      valinit = 1)

def update(scale):
    scaled = ixmap_scale(im, ixs, scale)
    HANDLE.set_data(scaled)
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

scale_slider.on_changed(update)

im = Image.open(PATH)
im = im.resize(
    (int(im.width*PREPROCESS_SCALE), int(im.height*PREPROCESS_SCALE)))
ixs = generate_ixmap(im, MIN_SCALE, True)

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax1.set_axis_off()
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
ax2.set_axis_off()

ax1.imshow(im)
HANDLE = ax2.imshow(im)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

`AxesImage` has a notion of both the data that it is to show (updated via `HANDLE.set_data` and the area in the data space it should cover (via `HANDLE.set_extent` ([docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/image_api.html#matplotlib.image.AxesImage.set_extent)).

You want to update both `set_extent` and the xlim/ylim of the Axes:

```py
def update(scale):
    ...
    HANDLE.set_data(scaled)
    ydim, xdim = scale.shape
    # the -.5 offset is because the pixel centers are at the integers
    HANDLE.set_extent([-.5, xdim - .5, -.5, ydim - .5])
    HANDLE.ax.set_xlim(-.5, xdim - .5)
    HANDLE.ax.set_ylim(-.5, ydim - .5)
```

For lots of details see
https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/imshow_extent.html